# can't do cosine similarity between 2 images, how to make both have the same length

Tags: python, face-recognition

I was doing some face verification stuff(I'm a newbie) first I vectorize the 2 pics I want to compare

```
filename1 = '/1_52381.jpg'
filename2 = '/1_443339.jpg'

img1 = plt.imread(filename1)
rows,cols,colors = img1.shape
img1_size = rows*cols*colors
img1_1D_vector = img1.reshape(img1_size).reshape(-1, 1)


img2 = plt.imread(filename2)
rows,cols,colors = img2.shape
img2_size = rows*cols*colors
img2_1D_vector = img2.reshape(img2_size).reshape(-1, 1)

(img2_1D_vector.shape,img1_1D_vector.shape)
```

and here I get the dim of the both vector which is: ((30960, 1), (55932, 1)).

My question is how to make them both of the same length do I need to reshape the picture to have the same size first? or I can do it after vectorize it? thanks for reading

Comment: This seems to be an image processing issue rather than a programming one, no? If it is really the latter, can't you find the answer in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to compute a cosine similarity you need your vectors to have the same dimension, and resizing one of the pictures before reshaping it into a vector is a good solution.

To resize, you can use one of image processing framework available in python.

*Note: they are different algorithm/parameters that can be use for resizing.*

```
# with skimage (you can also use PIL or cv2)
from skimage.transform import resize

shape = img1.shape
img2_resized = resize(img1, shape)

img1_vector = img1.ravel()
img2_vector = img2_resized.ravel()

# now you can perform your cosine similarity between img1_vector and img2_vector
# which are of the same dimension
```

you may wan't to downscale the bigger picture instead of upscaling the smaller one as upscaling may introduce more artefacts.
You may also want to work with a fixed size accross a whole dataset.